# Can I use Java to access the Lookback data?

Tags: java, rally, lookbackapi

Is there a way to access historical data from Java?  I am currently using the rally-rest-api (1.0.6) to pull task information out.  But I would like to expand my query to include historical data.  Is the Lookback API limited to Javascript?

Comment: what do you mean for "historical data"? and historical data from where?

Answer (score 1):

While Lookback API (LBAPI) isn't restricted to Javascript, Rally's AppSDK2 Javascript toolkit is currently the Rally API into which Rally-built hooks have been built for accessing LBAPI data. This is accomodated via the [Snapshotstore](https://developer.help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0p5/doc/#!/api/Rally.data.lookback.SnapshotStore).

Although AppSDK2 enjoys the benefit of LBAPI-specific data access functionality, there's nothing language-specific about LBAPI. It is a REST-based API that is fully accessible via any client that supports RESTful interaction with a webservice, java included. In fact you could utilize the same Apache commons functionality and Google GSON Json parsing utilities that are utilized by [Rally's Java REST API](https://developer.help.rallydev.com/java-toolkit-rally-rest-api), and also implement them in your own code to query against LBAPI directly. You'd be using the Apache and GSON libs to develop the LBAPI query hooks yourself though.

The Lookback API documentation:

https://rally1.rallydev.com/analytics/doc

Contains a workable summary of how to utilize the LBAPI REST endpoint, how to formulate queries, and what type/format of data to expect in response.

As LBAPI matures, I would expect that Rally's Java, .NET, and Ruby toolkits will expand to include built-in LBAPI query capability.