# Rally Lookback API for C#

Tags: c#, api, rally, lookbackapi

I’m having a hard time finding any information on how to retrieve snapshot data using the Rally REST API.  I noticed there is a Lookback toolkit for Java, but I am coding in **C#.**

In particular, I would like to retrieve *Schedule State* changes over time for Stories (aka Requirements).

Any related example would also be very helpful.
Thank you,
-Phil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no built-in support for Lookback API in [.NET REST tookit](https://github.com/RallyTools/RallyRestToolkitFor.NET) and in [Java REST toolkit](https://github.com/RallyTools/RallyRestToolkitForJava).
See also this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15350394/can-i-use-java-to-access-the-lookback-data)
As an imperfect workaround see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17599988/how-to-query-for-state-transitions) that mentions parsing Revisions. You may query on stories and fetch RevisionHistory,Revisions and Description, and iterate over results parsing Description of individual revisions for "SCHEDULE STATE changed" string.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  There is a Toolkit for Java which provides an interface for interacting with the Rally Lookback API.  Site: https://github.com/RallyTools/Rally-Lookback-Toolkit

Comment: Correct, but it is not built in the Rally java toolkit or officially supported.

Comment: I was saving the Revisions approach for Plan "B"