# How do I get burndown information from my iteration

Tags: .net, web-services, rest, rally

I'm playing around with the .NET api for the rest webservices.
I've looked up an iteration, and now I would like some data to build a burndown chart. I can find all tasks, and see estimates and todo, for a current image, but how do I find previous "snapshots"? Like, yesterday's ToDo.

The reason for doing this, is that the only way I've been able to "download" burndown charts as images, have been limited to a very small resolution and I need to present them on a big infoboard.

Comment: What did the docs say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Historic data is available from [LookbackAPI](https://rally1.rallydev.com/analytics/doc/#/manual).

LookbackAPI is language agnostic, but there is currently no built-in support for it in [Rally REST toolkit for .NET](https://github.com/RallyTools/RallyRestToolkitFor.NET)

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18723474/rally-lookback-api-for-c-sharp/18724406#18724406) is still current.